# spanning tree T of G is minimal regarding $w_1 \Longleftrightarrow$ T is minimal regarding $w_2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I am studying graph theory and im not getting forward on this problem.

Let G be a connected Graph with weight-functions $w_1,w_2 : E(G) \longrightarrow \mathbb R$.

For all $e, e' \in E(G) $ applies:
$$w_1(e) \leq w_1(e') \Longleftrightarrow w_2(e) \leq w_2(e')$$

Show:

spanning tree T of G is minimal regarding $w_1  \Longleftrightarrow$ T is minimal regarding $w_2$

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: A spanning tree is $w_1$-minimal if for every edge of the tree $e$, for every edge $e’$ that could be swapped out for $e$ to make another spanning tree, we have $w_1(e) \leq w_1(e’)$. That is, the tree is locally minimal.

Comment: Alternative hint: look at the algorithm(s) you know for finding a minimal spanning tree. (I suppose which of these hints is better depends on your background and prior knowledge of the subject.)